# How to transition away from Google Apps without losing e-mail

Tags: g-suite

All of the email from my company domain has been routed through Google Apps for Business (the old Gmail for Domains) for about 8 years. So, MX records for my domain all point to Google's email servers.

But now I'm selling my business - including that company domain - and need to migrate all my personal emails away from the company domain to my new personal domain name.

Once the sale of the business closes I won't have access to the DNS records for the domain. As a result I won't be able to control those MX records. I know I can simply change the MX records away from Google and point them to the business' domain mail server. But how do I do this without losing emails?

When I started using Google to handle my domain's email I set the TTL to 5 mins, changed the DNS MX Record and waited. It took about 20 hours and I'm sure I lost about 30% of my incoming emails as the MX records moved through propagation.

So, I'm trying to figure out how to switch off Google Biz Apps handling of the mail to the new server without losing a bunch of emails. Especially, now with all the activity involved in the business sale.

Any help from others that have been through this ordeal will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to handle MX transitions is to just have both the new  and the old system ready to somehow handle mail for the domain until DNS propagation is finished. Depending on the system, you can then use various methods to get mails that arrived onto the old system to the new one. This works as most (all?) mail servers don't rely on DNS entries to decide which domains they are reponsible for, but instead can be configured separately. This way, you never should loose a single mail during such a handover.

Note: I don't use G services and don't know if/how you can switch away the MX while Google still properly handles incoming mails. This might depend on where the DNS for the domain is hosted in the first place.

Also, I believe it would be a very good idea to hire an expert consultant to help you with this transition to avoid any legal unpleasantries with the new business owners due to mistakes during the DNS/mail transition.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would depend on what new service are you moving to.

Microsoft Exchange/Office 365 server or another Gmail address. Migration methods are very different for each one of them:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Migrate-G-Suite-mailboxes-to-Office-365-665dc56c-581c-4e35-8028-6bc1e8497016

https://www.lifewire.com/move-or-copy-mail-from-one-gmail-account-to-another-1171948